# How to delete particular List object in Java?

Tags: java, list

I have a list of around 100,000 employees in Java. Now I want to delete a particular employee object from list quickly. What are the possible ways to do it without iterating the whole list?
(If I iterate each object, compare the details then delete: this scenario takes lot of time)

Comment: UR_object_List.remove(object)

Answer (score 7):

You need a means of find the object quickly.  You could

- have an ArrayList sorted and then perform a binary search with Collections.binarySearch `O(log N)` Note: actually removing an element from an ArrayList is `O(n)` While LinkedList as `O(1)` for remove, a binary search on it would be pointless i.e. much slower than `O(N)`
- you could have a hash Set of Employee instead and removal would be `O(1)` amortised. You could use a `LinkedHashSet` if you would like to preserve some order such as order of insertion.
- you could make the object mutable and have a field like `enabled` which you set to `false` instead of actually removing it.  You could remove it later as a batch job at some time (overnight or on the weekend)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen SO isn't Quora though https://www.quora.com/Is-it-true-that-after-Brexit-Pluto-will-be-a-planet-in-the-UK-again ;)

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to delete a particular employee object from list ...

You can just use [List.remove](http://Now%20I%20want%20to%20delete%20a%20particular%20employee%20object%20from%20list%20quickly.%20What) to do this

> ... quickly

In practice, even though removing the item might be an `O(1)` operation, iterating over the full length of the list is `O(n)`, and is, as you susepcted, not very fast.

I feel that your problem would better be served by the power of a hashmap.  This has constant lookup and removal time.  The [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) class might suit your needs.  It maintains insertion order the same way a linked list does, but it also has constant time insertion and deletion.